# Express POST data and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, express, meteor

How do I implement writing POST data from express into an existing MongoDB collection? The collection is part of a Meteor app. Should I setup replication between the express MongoDB collection and the Meteor collection, or can I send the POST data straight into the Meteor collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution depends on your architecture and needs. I can see three options:

1) Implement an API endpoint in your Meteor application to handle the POST request and use this endpoint from your Express app.
Here is the link to some more information on this solution. [http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/REST_API#WebApp.connectHandlers and connect](http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/REST_API#WebApp.connectHandlers%20and%20connect)

2) In your Express app open connection to the Mongo database your Meteor app uses and insert / update the data straight to the database.

3) Connect your Express app to your Meteor app with DDP and treat your Express and update / insert the data from your Express app, treated as Meteor client.

Comment: Ok. I think I understand what I need to do for each. To clarify my question a little, I had planned to use Express only because I was told that Getting post data from an outside site wasn't something I should do in Meteor. Because it would load the whole meteor app to receive the POST. So I think I'm looking at 2 or 3.

Comment: If that was your concern, I highly recommend going with #1 and keeping things simple. Meteor doesn't need to load the whole stack into memory for each new request. You need to create a middleware to handle your request, it will work just as it would in Express and you'll get much better maintainability in the long run.

Comment: I'm not sure who told you that you shouldn't receive POST requests in Meteor, but most probably they have confused a few things. Meteor is built on top of Node.js and you get all Node functionality underneath. Just because Meteor itself targets easier client communication doesn't mean that you shouldn't use the functionality that's left unchanged – like handling REST API on the server side. It works like in any other Node.js application.

Comment: I linked to a meteorpedia article on solution 1. This site had a code example that was helpful for me to get started on that solution. Thanks for your help.